# ZeroMQ round-robin fail-over on disconnected peers

Tags: go, zeromq, distributed-system

I'm using ZeroMQ's multiple connect feature, to connect a single **`DEALER`** to 2 **`ROUTERS`**:

```
            +----> .Connect() --> ROUTER 1
           /
DEALER ---+------> .Connect() --> ROUTER 2
```

In my test, I send 10 mesages through the `DEALER`. I get back a nice even distribution of 5 messages to each of the `ROUTER`-s.

My problem is, if `ROUTER 1` goes away for some reason, the `DEALER` will still continue to queue messages for it, I think in the assumption that `ROUTER 1` will eventually come back. I end up with only 5 messages on `ROUTER 2`.

What I need to happen is for `DEALER` to ignore disconnected or failed peers. Is this possible?

I've tried setting **`ZMQ_SNDHWM`** and many others, but nothing seems to work.

The only alternative I can see is to do the failover myself, with separate sockets, heartbeats and ACK packets etc. It seems like such a basic pattern should already be implemented by ZeroMQ.

---

**Edit**: testing code

```
package main

import (
    "github.com/pebbe/zmq4"
    "time"
    "log"
    "fmt"
)

func receiveAll(sok *zmq4.Socket) (received int) {
    poller := zmq4.NewPoller()
    poller.Add(sok, zmq4.POLLIN)

    for {
        sockets, err := poller.Poll(100 * time.Millisecond)
        if err != nil {
            log.Print(err)
        }
        if len(sockets) > 0 {
            for _, s := range sockets {
                msg, _ := s.Socket.RecvMessageBytes(0)
                if string(msg[1]) != "Hello World" {
                    log.Fatalf("Unexpected message: %s\n", msg)
                }
                received ++
            }
        } else {
            return
        }
    }
}

func main() {

    dealer, _ := zmq4.NewSocket(zmq4.DEALER)
    router1, _ := zmq4.NewSocket(zmq4.ROUTER)
    router2, _ := zmq4.NewSocket(zmq4.ROUTER)

    router1.Bind("tcp://0.0.0.0:6667")
    router2.Bind("tcp://0.0.0.0:6668")

    dealer.Connect("tcp://0.0.0.0:6667")
    dealer.Connect("tcp://0.0.0.0:6668")

    router1.SetSubscribe("")
    router2.SetSubscribe("")
    dealer.SetSubscribe("")

    for i := 0; i < 10; i++ {
        dealer.SendBytes([]byte("Hello World"), 0)
    }

    time.Sleep(300 * time.Millisecond)

    count1 := receiveAll(router1)
    count2 := receiveAll(router2)

    fmt.Printf("Blue sky scenario: count1=%d count2=%d\n", count1, count2)

    // Shut down a peer
    router1.Close()
    time.Sleep(300 * time.Millisecond)

    for i := 0; i < 10; i++ {
        dealer.SendBytes([]byte("Hello World"), 0)
    }

    time.Sleep(300 * time.Millisecond)

    count := receiveAll(router2)

    fmt.Printf("Peer 1 offline: count=%d\n", count)

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> *What I need to happen is for* `DEALER` *to ignore disconnected or failed peers. **Is this possible ?***

Oh sure, it is. There is need to tweak the default ( inactive ) values, using you use-case specific settings in :

- a `.setsockopt(` **`ZMQ.IMMEDIATE`**`, 1 )` for not buffering message-instances for peer, that do not seem to be "alive"
- a `.setsockopt(` **`ZMQ.HEARTBEAT_IVL`**`, <ms> )` for sending heartbeats
- a `.setsockopt(` **`ZMQ.HEARTBEAT_TTL`**`, <ms> )` for a Time-To-Live setting
- a `.setsockopt(` **`ZMQ.HEARTBEAT_TIMEOUT`**`, <ms>)` for a timeout threshold
- a `.setsockopt(` **`ZMQ.HANDSHAKE_IVL`**`, <ms> )` for managing (re-)establishment timeouts.

For details, check your language binding and what native API version it actually uses under the hood. Most of these settings are available since native-API v 3.x, the most recent native-API v 4.2.2 documentation will help you tune the values and configuration strategies.

Comment: Thanks, upvoted, but I don't have enough reputation for it to be visible... :-)